# Find first TD with text in a TR with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am using JQuery to iterate through all TRs in a table,

but not all rows have values in the first cell.

```
<TR>
  <TD>3</TD>
  <TD>2</TD>
  <TD>1</TD>
</TR>
  <TD></TD>
  <TD>3</TD>
  <TD>2</TD>
<TR>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD></TD>
  <TD></TD>
  <TD>3</TD>
</TR>
```

How can i target the first TD in each row that is not empty and not just the first child?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your iteration code look like?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a simpler, more elegant solution:

```
$('tr').find('td:not(:empty):first').css('background', 'red');​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/JRcEf/

It just says in jQuery what you mean: "target the *first* `td` in each `tr` that is *not* empty".

Comment: This is great, i was hoping for a selector based method but couldn't get it right. Thanks!

Comment: @BarakChamo: Beware that this will require **jQuery** to handle the selector, it won't be able to hand off to the browser's own (much, much faster) selector engine. 99.9% of the time that doesn't matter, of course!

Answer (score 1):

This finds the first non-blank child `td` within each `tr`:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var $firstNonEmptyCell;

    $(this).children("td").each(function() {
        var $td = $(this);
        if ($td.text() === "") {
            $firstNonEmptyCell = $td;
            return false; // Breaks `each` loop
        }
    });

    // ...use `$firstNonEmptyCell` here
});
```

Or if you want a jQuery wrapper for all non-blank ones, it's a trivial use case for [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var nonBlankCells = $(this).children("td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() !== "";
    });

    // Use `nonBlankCells` here
});
```

Comment: Might be trivial, but doesn't beat the [one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13330866/1269037) ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tds = [];

$('#tableId tr').each(function()
{
  $(this).find('td').each(function()
  {
    if ( $(this).html() != '' )
    {
      tds.push($(this));
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

and voila in the `tds` variable you got your td tags